# Using Rvest to webscrape rankings

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am wanting to scrape all rankings from the following website:

https://www.glassdoor.com/ratingsDetails/full.htm?employerId=432&employerName=McDonalds#trends-overallRating

I have tried using CSS selectors, which tell me to use ".ratingNum", but it leaves me with blank data. I have also tried using the GET function, which results in a similar problem.

```
# Attempt 1
url <- 'https://www.glassdoor.com/ratingsDetails/full.htm?employerId=432&employerName=McDonalds#trends-overallRating'

webpage <- read_html(url)

rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.rankingNum')

rank_data <- html_table(rank_data_html)

head(rank_data)

# Attempt 2
res <- GET("https://www.glassdoor.com/ratingsDetails/full.htm",
       query=list(employerId="432",
                  employerName="McDonalds"))

doc <- read_html(content(res, as="text"))

html_nodes(doc, ".ratingNum")

rank_data <- html_table(rank_data_html)

head(rank_data)
```

I expect the result to give me a list of all of the rankings, but instead it is giving me an empty list, or a list that doesn't include the rankings.

Comment: You should note that the [terms of service](https://www.glassdoor.com/about/terms.htm) prohibit use of software "to scrape, strip or mine data from Glassdoor without our express written permission".

Comment: It's probably javascript-rendered content, meaning you can't use `rvest`. You'd have to use a package like `V8` to do so.

Comment: @neilfws currently _Sandvig v. Sessions_ seems to uphold legality to collect data, but it wouldn't prevent websites (and parent companies) from banning your IP outright (user beware)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is empty because you're `GET`ing an unpopulated HTML document. Frequently when this happens you have to resort to RSelenium and co., but Glassdoor's public-facing API actually has everything you need – if you know where to look.

*(Note: I'm not sure if this is officially part of Glassdoor's public API, but I think it's fair game if they haven't made more of an effort to conceal it. I tried to find some information, but their documentation is pretty meager. Usually companies will look the other way if you're just doing a smallish analysis and not slamming their servers or trying to profit from their data, but it's still a good idea to heed their ToS. You might want to shoot them an email describing what you're doing, or even ask about becoming an API partner. Make sure you adhere to their [attribution rules](https://www.glassdoor.com/developer/index.htm). Continue at your own peril.)*

Take a look at the network analysis tab in you browser's developer tools. You will see some `GET` requests that return JSONs, and one of those has the address you need. Send a `GET` and parse the JSON:

```r
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

ratings <- paste0("https://www.glassdoor.com/api/employer/432-rating.htm?",
                  "locationStr=&jobTitleStr=&filterCurrentEmployee=false")

req_obj <- GET(ratings)
cont <- content(req_obj)

ratings_df <- map(cont$ratings, bind_cols) %>% bind_rows()

ratings_df
```

You should end up with a dataframe containing ratings data. Just don't forget that the "ceoRating", "bizOutlook", and "recommend" are are proportions from 0-1 (or percentages if *100), while the rest reflect average user ratings on a 5-point scale:

```r
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  hasRating type                value
  <lgl>     <chr>               <dbl>
1 TRUE      overallRating       3.3  
2 TRUE      ceoRating           0.72 
3 TRUE      bizOutlook          0.42 
4 TRUE      recommend           0.570
5 TRUE      compAndBenefits     2.8  
6 TRUE      cultureAndValues    3.1  
7 TRUE      careerOpportunities 3.2  
8 TRUE      workLife            3.1  
9 TRUE      seniorManagement    2.9
```